# Number of roots and location of roots in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying exercises in complex analysis of an institute in which I don't study and got struck on this question.

Question: If 0<|a|<1 , then show that the equation $(z-1)^n e^z =a$ has all its roots simple.

I  thought of finding the derivative of the equation which is $(z-1)^{n-1}[n e^z +e^z(z-1)] $and which will have multiple root z=1 if n>1 . but question asks for proving the opposite . SO , what mistake I am making .

Kindly tell.

Comment: This is a good start! The only root of the derivative is $z=1$, as you've pointed out. Can $z=1$ be a root of the original equation?

Comment: @GregMartin no it can't be . But what does it implies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  First, I think that there's a mistake in the derivative.

Second, I think the theorem you want is that $f(z)$ will have multiple roots if and only if $f$ and $f'$ have a common factor.